# What is this plate on an exterior wall?

Tags: electrical, switch, exterior

A friend of mine's house has a plate like this on one of the exterior walls. What is it and what purpose does it serve?

[image: exterior wall plate]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a small photocell.  They work just like a switch by turning on/off via dusk to dawn.  They require moderate visibility, range in maximum wattage, and generally are only for tungsten lighting loads.
Though newer photocell switches are CFL/LED compatible.

Also, they usually direct wire to high voltage and need a permanent power source unless the owner is okay using a manual override switch.

Typically used for outdoor light automation.  Best to use LED bulbs though as dusk to dawn on-time can burn through a incandescents life cycle.

Answer (score 4):

It's an old photovoltaic sensor, possibly for exterior  light control.

Comment: +1- Just to add that a photovoltaic sensor is commonly used as a switch on a lighting circuit; turning lights on when no light is present (nighttime) and turning them off in the presence of light (daytime).

Comment: Technicality: that's a photo*conductive* sensor, not photovoltaic. Probably the old cadmium-sulphide type. The color & squiggly line are giveaways.